# LineRenderer doesn't apply material in 2D Unity5

Tags: c#, 2d, unity, materials

I'm making something that draw lines with mouse on top of everything (in 2D), but the color of the line is always *purple* even though I assign a material to the line renderer. I could change the color by using shader, but after that the line doesn't appear on the screen anymore.

**DrawLine.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isMousePressed;
    private List<Vector3> pointsList;
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    private GameObject lineDrawPrefab;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public GameObject lineDrawPrefabs;

    struct myLine
    {
        public Vector3 StartPoint;
        public Vector3 EndPoint;
    };

    void Awake()
    {
        isMousePressed = false;
        pointsList = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = true;
            lineDrawPrefab = GameObject.Instantiate(lineDrawPrefabs) as GameObject;
            lineRenderer = lineDrawPrefab.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = false;
            pointsList.Clear();
        }
        if(isMousePressed)
        {
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            mousePos.z=-5;
            if (!pointsList.Contains (mousePos)) 
            {
                pointsList.Add (mousePos);
                lineRenderer.SetVertexCount (pointsList.Count);
                lineRenderer.SetPosition (pointsList.Count - 1, (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool checkPoints (Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB)
    {
        return (pointA.x == pointB.x && pointA.y == pointB.y);
    }
}
```

**LineMaterial.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LineMaterial : MonoBehaviour {

    private LineRenderer line;

    void Awake()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        //line.material =  new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
        //line.SetColors(Color.green, Color.green);
        line.SetWidth(0.15f,0.15f);
        line.useWorldSpace = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which shader are you using?

Comment: @HamzaHasan Particles/Additive